# How to use a variable value for the key of another object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have something like :

```
var myMenu= [
  {
    'My English Title':function(menuItem,menu) 
                       { ... }
  }];
```

Now, I want the replace 'My English Title' by an other JSON structure value `LOC.MENU_TITLE`.

I have try:

```
var myMenu= [
  {
    LOC.MENU_TITLE:function(menuItem,menu) 
                       { ... }
  }];
```

But it doesn't work. Any one can give me an hint of how to get JSON value inside a JSON variable?

Edit:
This is to use the [Context Menu of Jquery](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/index.php) but I got a problem with all solutions below and it's when it's time to pass the String for the Separator. It doesn't show the separator because it pass the string into an object instead of just the string.

Example:

```
var menu1 = [
  {'Option 1':function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Option 1!"); } },
  $.contextMenu.separator,
  {'Option 2':function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Option 2!"); } }
];
```

Comment: This isn't JSON, it is just a JavaScript object.

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object Notation ... I guess we are talking the same language :P

Comment: JSON is a serialized form of JavaScript objects and as such has slightly different syntax requirements. JSON is represented always as a string, not a real object. It is parsed into real objects, or serialized in a string.

Comment: I think the confusion comes in because array and object literal notation is (practically) equivalent to JSON.

Comment: One thing to note is that a function would have no meaning in a JSON object  since it's meant to be an interchange format. You can't serialize a JS function and have it make any sense to say, PHP or Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var tempElement = {};
tempElement[ LOC.MENU_TITLE ] = function(menuItem, menu) {};

myMenu = [ tempElement ];
```

---

Addressing your edit.  Try the following

```
var myMenu = [ {}, $.contextMenu.separator, {} ];

myMenu[0][ LOC.MENU_TITLE ]  = function(menuItem, menu) {};
myMenu[2][ LOC.MENU_TITLE2 ] = function(menuItem, menu) {};
```

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript [object literals](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.5) expect the keys to be either an `Identifier`, a `String` literal or a `Number` literal, a workaround can be to build your object step by step, using the bracket notation:

```
var myMenu= [{}];
myMenu[0][LOC.MENU_TITLE] = function(menuItem,menu){ /*...*/ };
```

Note that the above isn't JSON.

JSON is a language-agnostic data interchange format,  its grammar differs from the JavaScript Object literals, basically by allowing only string keys and the values must be an object, array, number, string, or the literal names: `false`, `null` `true`.

Comment: Why object inside an array? Wouldn't `var myMenu = {}; myMenu[LOC.MENU_TITLE]` work as well?

Comment: The structure is from the jQuery ContextMenu plugin

Comment: This doesn't work, but Justin Johnson solution works. Trying to understand why...