# in javascript, when constructing an object, unable to use other objects' methods

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, methods

when constructing an object using methods from other objects as an attribute name get `Syntax Error: Unexpected token .` - cannot find correct syntax

```
var R = function(a) { this.arg = a; };
R.prototype.name = function() { return this.arg; }

var r1 = new R('abc');
var name1 = r1.name();        // => "abc"

var o1 = { 'abc': r1 }        // this works with constant
var o2 = { name1: r1 }        // does not work with variable (see answer)
var o3 = { r1.name(): r1 }    // this fails - syntax
var o4 = { 'abc': r1.name() } // this works
```

have tried `{ (r1.name()): r1 }`, but that fails as well.

---

please note that *strings* and *integers* are evaluated as `bareword`s whereas methods and variables are not:

```
var o5 = { e.1: 123 }          // fails
var o6 = { 'e.1': 123 }        // succeeds
var o7 = { 1: 123 }            // succeeds
var o8 = { '1': 123 }          // same as o7
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a variable value for the key of another object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224542/how-to-use-a-variable-value-for-the-key-of-another-object)

Comment: is a duplicate - a little simpler, but same answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var o2 = { name1: r1 }        // this works with variable
```

This has the same meaning as:

```
var o2 = { 'name1': r1 }
```

In other words, it's still treating `name1` as a literal string.  The key in an object literal *must* be a constant or a so-called "bareword" -- this is a restriction of the language.  Variables and function invocations cannot be used as keys in object literals (but they can be used as values).  Using variables will appear to work, but the variable name will be used as the key and not the variable's value.

You will have to do something like:

```
var o2 = {};
o2[name1] = r1;

var o3 = {};
o3[r1.name()] = r1;
```

Comment: ok - this makes sense.  I guess it goes without asking there is no `bareword` function. :-) sometimes this language just loves for you to keyboard

Comment: What would such a function do?  A bareword is a language element, not some kind of special value.

Comment: I understand - lame joke on my part

Answer (score 0):

```
var o4 = { 'abc', r1.name() }
```

this one should be:

```
var o4 = { 'abc': r1.name() }
```

Comment: right! problem is on the attribute name side.  will edit description above

Comment: i think cdhowie has the answer-- no dynamic keys in object literal syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own property setter

```
function setProperty (prop,val,obj) {
    if (typeof prop === "undefined" || typeof val === "undefined") return undefined;
    if (typeof obj === "undefined") obj = {};
    obj[prop] = val;
    return obj;
}

// use 1
var o1 = setProperty(r1.name(),r1);

// use 2
var o2 = {};
setProperty(r1.name(),r1,o2);
```

Comment: good idea, but I think if I were doing this I would write a `createObject` with arguments `arg0=name0, arg1=value1, ....` to return an object.

Comment: you're using the base object type `{}` which is different from `Object` or even `x = function (){}`.  All the above is doing is setting a property, first creating it if it doesn't exist.