# Access JSON or JS property using string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON array like this:

```
_htaItems = [
    {"ID":1,
     "parentColumnSortID":"0",
     "description":"Precondition",
     "columnSortID":"1",
     "itemType":0},
    {"ID":2,
     "parentColumnSortID":"0",
     "description":"Precondition",
     "columnSortID":"1",
    "itemType":0}]
```

I want to update this by passing the ID, column name and new value to a function:

```
    function updateJSON(ID, columnName, newValue)
    {
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < _htaItems.length; i++)
        {
            if (_htaItems[i].ID == ID)
            {
                ?????
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is, how do I update the value? I know I can do something like the following:

```
 _htaItems[x].description = 'New Value'
```

But in my cause, the column name is being passed as a string.

Comment: You have a JavaScript array, not JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a variable value for the key of another object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224542/how-to-use-a-variable-value-for-the-key-of-another-object)

Comment: @jagdipa Felix is right--no JSON here.  You have an array built using the array literal syntax which contains objects that were built with the object literal syntax.

Comment: @Felix - this is a possible duplicate to sundry questions, but I couldn't quickly find one that used square bracket notation more than one level deep.

Comment: @JAAulde: Does not really make a difference.

Comment: @Felix - I'm not arguing that--just stating why I answered rather than marked duplicate, and pointing out that you found what I could not.

Comment: @JAAulde: Ah I see, sorry. And no worries, sometimes it is surprisingly hard to find a good duplicate, although you *know* that it is there ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I dont know what the difference between the above and JSON is, so I will find out. One related question - is there an easier way to get to the item index I need without looping though the array?

Comment: @jagdipa: JSON is a data exchange format which *looks* like JavaScript object literal syntax, but it is not. JSON is more like XML.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can access an object property either with literal notation:

```
the.answer = 42;
```

Or with bracketed notation using a string for the property name:

```
the["answer"] = 42;
```

Those two statements do **exactly** the same thing, but in the case of the second one, since what goes in the brackets is a string, it can be any expression that resolves to a string (or can be coerced to one). So all of these do the same thing:

```
x = "answer";
the[x] = 42;

x = "ans";
y = "wer";
the[x + y] = 42;

function foo() {
    return "answer";
}
the[foo()] = 42;
```

...which is to set the `answer` property of the object `the` to `42`.

So if `description` in your example can't be a literal because it's being passed to you from somewhere else, you can use bracketed notation:

```
s = "description";
_htaItems[x][s] = 'New Value';
```

Comment: What na elequent explanation ! I've read thousands of articles and could't get THE answer. Just save my day. Thank you!

Comment: Beautiful explanation! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

_htaItems[x][columnName] = 'New Value';
Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: To be fair, it's probably the time it took you to press the "code-style" button ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use square bracket notation, just like you did for array index:

```
_htaItems[i][columnName] = newValue;
```

Comment: Well that was a embarassingly easy :D

Answer (score 0):

Just do `_htaItems[i][columnName] = newValue;`. It will change the property specified in `columnName` to `newValue`.