# json api fetching some weird keys

Tags: json, api

[image]

http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/?query=release:fred&fmt=json

i am working with this api.
i have fetched it successfully.

how can i access the value of those keys which have - between them, for ex- **status-id** **track-count**

Comment: Can you mention which programming language/method you are using to access the nodes ?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can access a property in 2 ways: `value.innervalue` or `value["innervalue"]`. You can access the properties using the 2nd way, as it works with dashes in the name.

Consider having a look at the following answer for better understanding if required
[Access JSON or JS property using string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027051/access-json-or-js-property-using-string)