# Accessing nested properties with dynamic property name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an object that is produced from this JSON:

```
{
    "data":  {
        "Meta Data": {
            "1. Information": "Monthly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
            "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
            "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-08-18",
            "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
        },
        "Monthly Time Series": {
            "2017-08-18": {
                "1. open": "73.1000",
                "2. high": "74.1000",
                "3. low": "71.2800",
                "4. close": "72.4900",
                "5. volume": "285933387"
            },
            "2017-07-31": {
                "1. open": "69.3300",
                "2. high": "74.4200",
                "3. low": "68.0200",
                "4. close": "72.7000",
                "5. volume": "451248934"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using `Object.keys()`, I was able to get the key "*Monthly time series*", but how can I access  the keys within it? I want to run a for loop through the keys present in the "*Monthly time series*" key. How can I do that?

Comment: `Reflect.ownKeys(JSON.parse(data)["Monthly Time Series"])`, you have to try a recursive approach

Comment: Unexpected token 'o' in Json @Hitmands after doing that

Comment: Do you have a json or a javascript object?

Comment: I am getting this json object as response from an ajax call @Hitmands

Comment: Why would you use `Object.keys()` to access a not-random property such as `"Monthly Time Series"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable value for the key of another object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224542/how-to-use-a-variable-value-for-the-key-of-another-object)

Comment: What else do you suggest? @Andreas

Comment: `var monthlyTimeSeries = object["data"]["Monthly Time Series"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the array of keys, but instead of for...loop I suggest to iterate over the array of keys with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Code:

```js
const obj = {"data": {"Meta Data": {"1. Information": "Monthly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes","2. Symbol": "MSFT","3. Last Refreshed": "2017-08-18","4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"},"Monthly Time Series": {"2017-08-18": {"1. open": "73.1000","2. high": "74.1000","3. low": "71.2800","4. close": "72.4900","5. volume": "285933387"},"2017-07-31": {"1. open": "69.3300","2. high": "74.4200","3. low": "68.0200","4. close": "72.7000","5. volume": "451248934"}}}};

Object
  .keys(obj.data['Monthly Time Series'])
  .forEach(function (k) {
    console.log(obj.data['Monthly Time Series'][k]['1. open']);
  });
```

Comment: For accessing the values of "1.open" inside "Monthly time series, what can I do? It shows undefined, if I repeat the above method!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the keys the very same way as you're accessing them now through `Object.keys` function.

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"data": {\
    "Meta Data": {\
        "1. Information": "Monthly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",\
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",\
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-08-18",\
        "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"\
    },\
    "Monthly Time Series": {\
        "2017-08-18": {\
            "1. open": "73.1000",\
            "2. high": "74.1000",\
            "3. low": "71.2800",\
            "4. close": "72.4900",\
            "5. volume": "285933387"\
        },\
        "2017-07-31": {\
            "1. open": "69.3300",\
            "2. high": "74.4200",\
            "3. low": "68.0200",\
            "4. close": "72.7000",\
            "5. volume": "451248934"\
        }\
}}}');

console.log(Object.keys(data['data']["Monthly Time Series"]));
```

Output:

```
(2) ["2017-08-18", "2017-07-31"]
```

---

Ah, after your edit, if you want to loop through them, you don't need `Object.keys` function - you can simply iterate through the object like this:

```
for (var i in data['data']['Monthly Time Series'])
    console.log(i, data['data']['Monthly Time Series'][i])
```

`i` will contain your key

---

Per comments:

```
var obj = {"data": {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Monthly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-08-18",
        "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Monthly Time Series": {
        "2017-08-18": {
            "1. open": "73.1000",
            "2. high": "74.1000",
            "3. low": "71.2800",
            "4. close": "72.4900",
            "5. volume": "285933387"
        },
        "2017-07-31": {
            "1. open": "69.3300",
            "2. high": "74.4200",
            "3. low": "68.0200",
            "4. close": "72.7000",
            "5. volume": "451248934"
        }
}}}

Object.keys(obj.data["Monthly Time Series"]).map(function(key, index){ return obj.data["Monthly Time Series"][key]["1. open"]; });
```

To get one value from the array:

```
(2) ["73.1000", "69.3300"]
```

or:

```
Object.keys(obj.data["Monthly Time Series"]).map(function(key, index){ return Object.values(obj.data["Monthly Time Series"][key]); });
```

to get all values (they won't be concated though)

Comment: For accessing the values of "1.open" inside "Monthly time series, what can I do? It shows undefined, if I repeat the above method!

Comment: `1. open` isn't within `Monthly time series` - it's `data['data']['Monthly Time Series']['2017-07-31']['1. open']`

Comment: I did something like this            Object.keys(response.data['Monthly Time Series']).forEach(function(k){
             console.log(Object.keys(k["1. open"]));  It gives undefined on the console

Comment: Please specify what you want to do - right now you are getting the keys of result of `forEach` loop, which indeed returns `undefined` (`forEach` always returns `undefined`). Do you want to get the values of the lowest level within your `Monthly Time Series`?

Comment: yes I want to get the value of lowest level within Monthly Time Series